# Too long horizontal line

Tags: pdftex

I'm creating a table. Under the table I added an horizontal line in order to add a note with *. I used the following string:

> ```
>  \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
> ```

Unfortunately the horizontal line seems to be too long respect to the margins of the table.
NB: the caption will be under the note *

Any suggestion to solve such simple problem?

[image]

Example:

> ```
> ............      
> \bottomrule     
> \end{tabular}    
>  }        
> \vspace{0.1cm}        
>  \tiny *this is my note.     
>  \end{center}    
>  \vspace{-0.3cm}
>  \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
>  \caption[] {
>  \footnotesize \textbf{my caption} \\
>   ![my caption is ....][2]
>   } \\
>   \label{tab: Table 3.1} 
>   \end{table*}
>   \end{landscape}
> ```

Best

Comment: A compilable example showing the problem would be welcome. Not just a line of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Define the `tabular*` with

```
\begin{tabular*}{@{} .... @{}}
```

This deletes the `\tabcolsep` at the beginning and end.

However, using `tabularx` or `threeparttable` or ... maybe a better choice.

Comment: Doesn't the `tabular*` environment take an additional argument that specifies the table's intended width?

Comment: The use of @{} on the beginning and end of tabular doesn't influence on table width but on start and end table contents. So correct use in this case is \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ ... } (if you stick with tabular).